# How to prevent vue package styles to be applied to parent page

Tags: css, vue.js

I created a simple vue component that is loaded from a normal web page which contains own styles.
Using any type of vue frontend framework like *vue-bootstrap* or *fish-ui* those styles get applied to the whole page, which ends up in crashing the parent pages styles, because the included styles also have base element styles like `body` or `::selection, etc.

What is the way to prevent this?

I also realized that the parent pages css applies to the bootstrap / [fish-ui](https://github.com/myliang/fish-ui) components. For instance: `<fish-input label="xxlabel"/>` creates a `<label>` component which is affected because it does not get a data-id.

Comment: If the styles are in the `style` tag then you can put the `scoped` option and it will limit to the component. Looks like this:
`<style scoped>...</style>`

Comment: styles are imported from the package / the component, no custom styles in style tag

Comment: What is the collision is it naming or overriding?

Comment: Same identifier names, so I guess overriding?

Comment: then you need to rename, just add `something_` to the style.